# window.closed is sometimes true although tab is not closed

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular app that opens a link to an external site in a new tab when I click a button and then checks in an interval, if the tab is closed and when it is closed do stuff.

This works sometimes, but sometimes this doesn't work. When I check if the tab is closed with window.closed it is sometimes true, although the tab is not closed.

This issue appeared about a week or two ago and hasn't happened before then. I made no changes at all (the app is running for 2 months on a server without any code changes or anything). I also tried an old version of Chrome and another PC and the issue is still there.

The code looks like this

```
webUrl = "https://www.google.com"
this.otherWindow = window.open(webUrl, 'otherWindowCtx');
const interval = setInterval(async () => {
   if (this.otherWindow.closed) {
      doStuff();
      clearInterval(interval );
   }
}, 5000);
```

The thing is, when webUrl is the link to Google (or almost any other site) it works as expected, but when I open the correct site that I need to open, it doesn't work. Is there anything a site could do to interfere somehow? Or is there an alternative way that I could try to open an external site in a new window and check when it is closed?

Comment: the issue is that when you navigate to a new location in the new opened window, closed will be set to true

Comment: read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/closed)

Comment: This happens even if I don't do anything in the new window. Can the window itself navigate somewhere else (resulting in window.closed == true), when the url in the browser stays the same?

And if this is the issue, is there a way to circumvent this? I am only interested in the tab closing.

Comment: I've just submitted a bug request to the chrome team

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1338958

Comment: Ok, thank you. But is there any alternative that I can use to check if the tab was closed?